# Debugging a string comparison part with Runtime error

Tags: c, debugging, c-strings, strcmp

Numeric addresses for computers on the international network, ‘Internet’ has four parts, separated by periods, of the form   xxx.yyy.zzz.mmm    where  xxx ,  yyy ,  zzz , and  mmm  are positive integers. Locally, computers are usually known by a nickname as well.

**Sample Data**

```
IP address       Name
111.22.3.44      platte
555.66.7.88      wabash
111.22.5.66      green
0.0.0.0          none
```

A pair of computers are said to be in same locality when the first two components of the addresses are same. Given the details of some computers, design an algorithm and write a C program to display a list of messages identifying each pair of computers from the same locality. In the messages, the computers should be identified by their nicknames. In this example, the message to be displayed will be Machines platte and green are on the same local network.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void main()
{
    int n,p,i,j;
    char s[20][20],na[10][10];
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i < n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%s%s",s[i],na[i]);
        p=0;
        j=0;
        while(p!=2)
        {
            j++;
            if(s[i][j]=='.')
            p++;
        }
        s[i][j]='\0';
    }
    for(i=0;i < n-1;i++)
    for(j=i+1;j < n;j++)
    if(strcmp(s[i],s[j])==0)
    printf("Machines %s and %s are on the same local network",na[i],na[j]);
}
```

The code doesn't produce an output at all (runtime error) and I can't seem to figure out why.
EDIT : No compiler errors or warnings. Just execution gives me  blank output screen.

Comment: This is C code and should be tagged (only) as such; in C++ there are better ways to do all of this. Also `main` should return `int`. C99 allows implementation-defined return types but for portability you should use `int`.

Comment: Please provide the error message you are receiving.

Comment: EDIT : No compiler errors or warnings. Just execution gives me blank output screen.

Comment: Is that *really* your full input data, those column headers included ? and no actual value provided for `n` ?

Comment: Can't reproduce: http://ideone.com/e2kr0H

Comment: SO isn't a debugging service. Compile with symbols, run the code inside a debugger to trace through the program(s) line by line inspecting the values of the relevant variables to learn what is really going on. If then a *specific* question arises feel free to come back here.

Answer (score 0):

Your code produced the desired output on my machine.
It is probable that you are forgetting to enter 'n' the number of addresses to take as input or are providing less addresses than 'n'.